# converting JSONArray to POJO class List<type>, not able to converting

Tags: java, arrays, json

Please find the below code, that I am trying to set JSONArray of objects into the `SET` method of type `List<type>`.

```
public class SalesOrder {

    public static SalesOrder fromJSONObject(JSONObject o)
    {
        SalesOrder sa=new SalesOrder();
        sa.setOrderNumber(o.getString("order_number"));
        sa.setCustomerName(o.getString("customer_name"));
        sa.setOrder_files(o.getJSONArray("order_files"));
        return sa;

    }

    private String orderNumber;
    private String customerName;

    List<OrderFile> order_files;

    public List<OrderFile> getOrder_files() {
        return order_files;
    }
    public void setOrder_files(List<OrderFile> order_files) {
        this.order_files = order_files;
    }
}
```

But I am not able to set the value, it throws the error

> The method setOrder_files(List) in the type SalesOrder is
>   not applicable for the arguments (JSONArray).

Please find my `order_files` JSONArray

```
order_files":[  
   {  
      "file_name":"05_06_Field_lenghts_Requirements.pdf",
      "file_type":"Invoice",
      "file_id":"59c9ede7c3c867a6b269e111"
   },
   {  
      "file_name":"ideas.JPG",
      "file_type":"Packaging List",
      "file_id":"59c9ee65c3c867a6b269e113"
   }
]
```

Please find my POJO Class for OrderFiles

```
public class OrderFile {

    String file_id;
    String file_name;
    String file_type;


    public String getFile_id() {
        return file_id;
    }
    public void setFile_id(String file_id) {
        this.file_id = file_id;
    }
    public String getFile_name() {
        return file_name;
    }
    public void setFile_name(String file_name) {
        this.file_name = file_name;
    }
    public String getFile_type() {
        return file_type;
    }
    public void setFile_type(String file_type) {
        this.file_type = file_type;
    }
}
```

Based out of the comments received - Am trying to convert JSONArray to ArrayList and trying to pass as parameter to `sa.setOrder_files()`

```
   List<OrderFile> filelist=new ArrayList<OrderFile>();
    JSONArray filearray= o.getJSONArray("order_files");
    if(filearray!=null)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<filearray.length();i++)
        {
            filelist.add(filearray.getString(i));
        }
    }
    sa.setOrder_files(filelist);
```

But am getting error while adding item in the arraylist.

> Error : The method add(OrderFile) in the type List is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Comment: your method `setOrder_files(List<OrderFile> order_files)` expect a list of `OrderFile` as  parameter and `o.getJSONArray("order_files")` return a `JSONArray` object.

Comment: Just look at your object types.... You're trying to add a string to a list that holds your custom object

Comment: Suggestion: Use Gson or Jackson to convert JSON into POJO

Answer (score 1):

```
 sa.setOrder_files(o.getJSONArray("order_files"));
```

This line is the issue, your function setOrder_files expects a List instead of JSON Array.

You should change the argument of the function or send a list instead of the JSON array.

```
public class SalesOrder {

    public static SalesOrder fromJSONObject(JSONObject o)
    {
        SalesOrder sa=new SalesOrder();
        sa.setOrderNumber(o.getString("order_number"));
        sa.setCustomerName(o.getString("customer_name"));
        sa.setOrder_files(o.getJSONArray("order_files"));
        return sa;

    }

    private String orderNumber;
    private String customerName;

    JSONArray order_files;

    public JSONArray getOrder_files() {
        return order_files;
    }
    public void setOrder_files(JSONArray order_files) {
        this.order_files = order_files;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks., Instead of this approach., am trying to convert JSONArray to ArrayList ( list of Order_Files ) and passing to `sa.setOrder_files()`. But still receiving an error. Update those code along with the error.